# SQL for json path returning invalid json format and incomplete json result

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

This query works perfect

`SELECT * FROM application_info WHERE id IN (20002, 20001)`

However when I add `FOR JSON PATH` I get a `json` that is invalid and the data is incomplete.

`SELECT * FROM application_info WHERE id IN (20002, 20001) FOR JSON PATH`

An example of the `json` I am getting back is below. Notice how it just ends abruptly. Obviously the `FOR JSON PATH` is causing the error as the query without it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
[{
    "id": 20002,
    "app_status": "Active",
    "true_up": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": 20001,
    "app_status": "Active",
    "true_up": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": 20002,
    "app_status": "Inactive",
    "true_up": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": 20002,
    "app_status": "Active",
    "true_up": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": 20002,
    "app_status": "Inactive",
    "true_
```

Sample table data `application_info`

```
id         app_status      true_up
-----------------------------------
20003       Active          Yes
20002       Active          Yes
20004       Active          Yes
20003       Active          Yes
20001       Active          Yes
20002       Active          Yes
20002       InActive        Yes
20003       Active          Yes
20005       InActive        Yes
20002       Active          Yes
20002       Active          Yes
20003       Active          Yes
20001       Active          Yes
20002       Active          Yes
```

Comment: Please provide sample data so we can replicate this behavior.

Comment: Ok will do add that ASAP

Comment: Are you checking the length of the JSON output in SSMS? It has a limit of how much characters it outputs for XML and JSON constructs. Try to assign the output to a `nvarchar(max)` variable and check its length, such as `select len(@myjsonvar);`.

Comment: No I am not checking the limit. Mhhh...this seems like it could be the issue. Will do what you say.

Comment: The length of the output is `129507`, I did it with just id =`20002` and got a different cut off point with length `67875`. I think it is the `json` length.

Comment: Did it with `TOP 50` and got correct `json`. I will look into a way to get all the results.